# Автоматический переход

Tags: javascript, html, pure_js

Как сделать чтобы через 8 секунд с страницы 1.html был автоматический переход на страницу 2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('window.location="2.html"',8000);
</script>
```

Comment: А почему не воспользоваться тегом:

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="x; URL=http://blabla">
    <!-- х - время в секундах до начала новой загрузки документа;
    URL - адрес документа в Интернете (может не указываться) -->

Comment: Потому что исчезает всякая возможность повлиять на процесс. Он ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО перенаправит через 8 секунд(причем, вроде, с момента загрузки тэга, а не всей страницы)

Comment: А ваш способ дает возможножность возврата на страницу, с которой был редирект? Ну и к тому же, отключенный JavaScript в браузере, ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОСТЬ сожрет.

Comment: А остались такие кары еще? :D

Comment: @Dex, да, дает, конечно. 
Отключенный яваскрипт... Отключенный яваскрипт наоборот позволит продвинутому люду запретить редирект по желанию всяких там Александров. Так что это скорее плюс. Совсем продвинутый люд может запретить редиректы вообще..

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="8;url=2.html>
```